# Problema na importação do Springboot no arquivo pow.xml

Tags: java, eclipse

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.6.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode dar uma olhada nessa outra questão para ver algumas possibilidades: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654666/spring-boot-pom-xml-failure-to-transfer

Comment: A finalidade do stackoverflow é ser um repositório de conhecimento, mas para que isso seja possível, as respostas precisam ser independentes. Recomendo que edite sua resposta contendo sua sugestão de solução, mesmo que seja baseada no link. Assim, sua resposta permanece válida mesmo que a resposta se perca, e o link uma referência, caso o autor ou o leitor queira se aprofundar mais.